# Catching error in angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, angular-promise, web-frontend

If client send POST request, where LicenseNumber is already existing in database  (has to be unique), server is sending response:

> {"errorCode":"Validation Error",
>
> "errorMessage":"Invalid inputs.",
>
> "errors":["Such license number already exists"]}

How I could get "errors" to show it in my view?

I tried it with below method:

```
   update(doctor: Doctor): Promise<Doctor> {
    const url =`${this.doctorsUrl}/${doctor.id}`;
    return this.http.put(url, JSON.stringify(doctor), {headers: this.headers})
    .toPromise()
    .then(() => doctor)
    .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private handleError(errors: any): Promise<any> {
    console.error('An error occurred', errors);
    return Promise.reject(errors.message || errors);
  }
```

but if I send test bad request in console I get regular 400 BAD_REQUEST ERR.

So, how I could catch this error?

Thanks, Bartek

Answer (score 0):

What's the result from the server? It sounds a lot like an HTTP400 (Bad Request) is the correct result for such an error.

To show your error you should either return the error message or use some sort of Toast/Snackbar to push it on the screen.

You could use

```
private handleError(errors: any): Promise<any> {
   console.error('An error occurred', errors);
   // this is agular material snackbar
   this.snackBar.open('Error occurred ' + errors.message, null, {
        duration: 5000
   });
   // alternate option - will use the browser alert
   alert('Error occurred ' + errors.message);
   return Promise.reject(errors.message || errors);
}
```